# Setting a relationship between Users to access a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm teaching myself Rails and I'm trying to setup a collaboration relationship kind of like Github adds collaborators to projects. My models look like this:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees
    has_many :users, through: :employees
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :restaurants, through: :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The employee table also has a user_type column to handle permissions within the project (restaurant). I can't figure out how to make my employee_controller set this relationship. Users primary key is :email so I'm guessing a form should be able to receive the :email parameter, check if such a user with the inputed email exists, and add the relationship to the employees table.

I'm looking to be able to do something like this:

```
Restaurant_A = Restaurant.create(restaurant_params)
User_A.restaurants = Restaurant_A
Restaurant_A.employees = User_B
```

I think my models might be wrong but essentially I'd like to be able to have users with the ability to create a restaurant as well as be added as employees of another restaurant/their own restaurants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is all right - no problem with that.

What you are trying to accomplish, you can accomplish that by following:

```
restaurant_a = Restaurant.create(restaurant_params)
# Remember to name it 'restaurant_a', it is convention in Ruby
user_a.restaurants << restaurant_a
```

`<<` is an operator that inserts left hand side thing into its right hand thing. So in our case, it will insert `restaurant_a` into the list of `restaurants` that are associated with `user_a`, and then you call `save` operation on your `user_a` like `user_a.save`.

Same case is on the other side:

```
restaurant_a.employees << user_b
# According to Ruby convention, you shouldn't start your variable
# name with an upper case letter, and you should user a convention
# called 'snake_type' naming convention. So instead of naming
# your variable like 'firstDifferentUser', name it 'first_different_user'
# instead.
restaurant_a.save # To successfully save the record in db
```

**Edit:**

For creating a form:

```
<%= form_for(@restaurant, @employee) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

And you need to define `@restaurant` and `@employee` in your employee's controller `new` action, because you are gonna create a new employee for a particular restaurant.

Comment: I see, thank you Arslan :). Managed to do the first part upon creation of the restaurant. Will let you know if I get stuck at the other side of the association when adding employees.

Comment: Definitely stuck. Do you mind telling me how you would go ahead and build a form to retrieve the :email parameter in Rails 4? After that I'm guessing I can do something along the lines of User.find_by(email: params[:email])

Comment: You want the form where user could come, put his email, and then press the submit button? Is that how you want to receive the `email` parameter?

Comment: So, let's say a user created a restaurant and is now managing it. The user clicks in a button called Add Employee and it takes him to a form in the route /restaurant/:id/employees/new . Here there is a form with a single input :email and a submit button. After submission, you either get a flash message saying no user with that email found or you are redirected to restaurant/:id/employees and see the newly added user. PS: I'm using the employees_controller to handle this.